# How can I know the retained class name or keyword when I use navigation framework in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The following code is from the project at https://github.com/mycwcgr/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic

The project use the latest navigation framework, I find there are some retained class name such as *CameraFragmentDirections*, *GalleryFragmentArgs*.

The system have no prompt information for these class name, must I remember these keywords by myself?

**Code**

```
 /** Method used to re-draw the camera UI controls, called every time configuration changes */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun updateCameraUi() {

        // Listener for button used to view last photo
        controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.photo_view_button).setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                    CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
        }
    }


   /** Fragment used to present the user with a gallery of photos taken */
   class GalleryFragment internal constructor() : Fragment() {

       /** AndroidX navigation arguments */
       private val args: GalleryFragmentArgs by navArgs()

   }
```

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but I don't understand what the question you ask means. Can you please elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I mean that I have to remember these class name such as `CameraFragmentDirections`, `GalleryFragmentArgs` in order to use navigation framework. You know that class name  `CameraFragmentDirections` is based 'CameraFragment' and plus 'Directions', I have to remember these rules without any prompt information by Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not need to remember these things by yourself, if you know of a trick.

For example, if you don't remember the "keyword" `Directions`, but you know you want to do something related to `CameraFragment`, you can start typing e.g. `CameraFragm` in Android Studio. It will then suggest `CameraFragment` and `CameraFragmentDirections` for you. That way you can find `CameraFragmentDirections` easily even though you did not remember the keyword `Directions`.

There are not that many keywords to worry about though. After working with the Navigation framework for a while, you will remember them all.

If you are curious, you can find the generated classes here after a build:

```
./app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/...
```

e.g. after a debug build:

```
./app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragmentDirections.java
```

If you are even more curious, the code that generates these classes is here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/src/main/kotlin/androidx/navigation/safe/args/generator/java/JavaNavWriter.kt

There you can for example find this code:

```
internal fun Destination.toClassName(): ClassName {
    val destName = name ?: throw IllegalStateException("Destination with actions must have name")
    return ClassName.get(destName.packageName(), "${destName.simpleName()}Directions")
}
```

which is the code that decides what name `CameraFragmentDirections` gets. (Note `"${destName.simpleName()}Directions"` at the end.)